# railsでサーバーが立ち上がらず、sassc でエラーが出る: cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Rails でターミナルにてサーバーを立ち上げようとするのですが
エラーが下記のように出て立ち上げることができません。

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
```

不思議なのが上記の操作をしても

```
continue.
Make sure that gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
succeeds before bundling.
```

と出て

```
gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/
```

を実行し、そのあと `bundle install` しても

```
An error occurred while installing sassc (2.3.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
succeeds before bundling.
```

と出て堂々巡りしています。

これは一体何が足りないのでしょうか？

（sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6)がgemファイルに足りないと記載があるかと思いますが
写真の通り,存在しているように思います。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記が `$ gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` 
を実行したときのログになります。

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sassc:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0/ext
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200420-17161-1wmp45i.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/ast.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [ast.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sassc-2.3.0/gem_make.out
```

### 追記

上のエラーを解決した後別のエラーが出たので、別の質問として投稿しています: [CentOS 6でのNode.jsのアップグレード方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65861/19110)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今回の主原因はこのエラーです：

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

`-std=c++11` というオプションが C++ コンパイラのとあるバージョンから使えるようになったのですが、それが使えないというエラーです。おそらく C++ コンパイラの導入に失敗しているか、長らくバージョンアップされていません。

あとは OS やお使いのパッケージマネジャーにあわせた対処をすることになります。g++ や clang++ などの C++ コンパイラをインストールしたり更新したりしてください。

例：

- Ubuntu、apt

  - `apt update` & `apt install build-essential`

    - 必要に応じて `sudo` を先頭につけてください。
  - `g++ --version` が 4.7 未満であれば古いので更新してください。
- CentOS、yum

  - `yum update` & `yum install gcc gcc-c++ make`

    - 必要に応じて `sudo` を先頭につけてください。
    - 補足：いずれ必要になることをみこして gcc 等も入れていますが、不要であれば gcc-c++ のみで結構です。
  - `g++ --version` が 4.7 未満であれば古いので更新してください。

    - たとえば 2020 年 4 月現在、CentOS 6 の yum を使うとデフォルトでは [g++ 4.4.7 がインストールされる](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/)ので古いです。ひとつの解決法として、[Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/) にある devtoolset からインストールできる g++ を使う方法があります。devtoolset にはいくつかバージョンがあるので[検索して](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/?search=devtoolset)ご自身にあったものを選んでください。ここでは 2020 年 4 月現在最新の devtoolset-8 を使う例を紹介します。

      ```sh
      yum install centos-release-scl  # Software Collections にアクセスできるようにする
      yum install devtoolset-8        # devtoolset-8 をインストール（g++ を含め各種バイナリについて新しいバージョンのバイナリがダウンロードされます）
      scl enable devtoolset-8 bash    # devtoolset-8 系列のバイナリを使うように設定された Bash を起動
      ```

      最後の行は Bash を立ち上げる度に実行する必要があります。面倒くさければ、[この回答](https://serverfault.com/a/851154/412043)のように `source scl_source enable` を `~/.bashrc` に書いておくなどの方法があります。
- macOS

  - macOS のデフォルトでは Xcode の Command Line Tools をインストールすることで clang++ を入れます。
  - `clang++ --version` が 4 未満であれば古いので更新してください（正確には 3.x のどこかでいけるようになっているはずですが、3.x はどちらにせよ古いので更新してください）。設定の「ソフトウェアアップデート」や [`softwareupdate` コマンド](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT200113)から Command Line Tools を更新することで clang を更新できます。

更新した後再度 `gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` を試してみて、成功すれば `bundle install` を行い、成功すればそのあとサーバーを立ち上げてみてください。

### 補足

以下、それ以外のメッセージについての解説です。

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
```

これは「sqlite3 を使いたいけど、Gemfile に書かれている gem の在りか一覧を探してもそんな名前の gem 無いよ」というエラーです。後述する通り sassc のインストールに失敗しているため `bundle install` が中途半端な状態で終わっており、実際 sqlite3 がインストールされていなかったのでしょう。なお、Gemfile に sqlite3 が書かれていないよ、というエラーではありません。

上のエラーメッセージには `bundle install` をせよと書かれているのでやってみます。`bundle install` の出力によると sassc のインストールが怪しく、`gem install sassc` をせよと書かれています。質問者さんは `gem install sassc` の出力を無視されていたようですが、このログを見ると `gem install sassc` が失敗していると分かります。

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sassc:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

あとはログの細かいところを読んで、失敗原因を探る作業になるという訳です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
clangのダウンロードがされていないようで、
Xcodeをダウンロードすればが自動的にインストールされるということでやってみましたができないようです。バージョンを確かめるコマンドではこのように出ます。

[vagrant@localhost myapp]$ clang++ --version
-bash: clang++: コマンドが見つかりません

初心者で申し訳ないのですが
現在Vagrantを使っているのですが
このvagrant@localhostというところで$ clang++ --versionを
試すと上記のように出ますが
ExitコマンドでVagrantから抜けた時に
$ clang++ --versionを試すと下記のように出ます。
おそらくこれは自分のPC環境に戻ったからかと思われますが
Vagrant環境にてclang++をインストールする必要があるということでしょうか？
その場合はどういった方法がありますでしょうか？

Comment: $ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: なるほど、Vagrant 上の環境だったのですね。でしたら話が変わってきます。先に私が環境を確認すれば良かったですね、すいません。Vagrant 上で使っているゲスト OS は何でしょうか？

Comment: Ubuntu と CentOS の例を追加しました。Vagrant 上で `bundle install` されている場合、Vagrant 上に各種バイナリが必要ですのでインストールしてください。

Comment: こちらこそ丁寧に教えていただき大変感謝しております。ありがとうございます。
下記の操作を試してみたのですが失敗しているようです。これはどういった原因が考えられますでしょうか？

[vagrant@localhost myapp]$ yum install gcc gcc-c++ make
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
??????????:fastestmirror

Comment: [vagrant@localhost myapp]$ clang++ --version
-bash: clang++: コマンドが見つかりません

Comment: その yum コマンドでインストールされるのは clang++ ではなく g++ です。C++ コンパイラにはいくつか種類があり、macOS でよく使われているのは clang++ で、CentOS 等でよく使われているのは g++ です。`g++ --version` だと見つかることでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに下記のように確認できました。ですがそのあとgem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source をやっても同じエラーになります。まだ他にインストールが足りないということでしょうか？

[root@localhost ~]# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
をやっても同じ
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
とでます。

Comment: g++ のバージョンが古いですね……。CentOS は 6 ですか、7 ですか？

Comment: CentOS release 6.10 (Final)と出ております。

Comment: アップデートした方が良さそうでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107027/discussion-between-ligtning-and-nekketsuuu)しましょう。