# CentOS 6でのNode.jsのアップグレード方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, vagrant

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65787/19110)の続きで、Vagrantで構築したCentOS 6上でRailsサーバーを立ち上げるコマンド

```
rails server -b 192.168.33.10/ -d
```

を行ったところ、下記のように表示され

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /home/vagrant/rails_lessons/myapp/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/vagrant/rails_lessons/myapp/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

`rails webpacker:install` のコマンドを実行したところ

```
Webpacker requires Node.js >= 8.16.0 and you are using 0.10.48
Please upgrade Node.js nodejs.org/en/download
```

と出ました。
これはNode.jsをアップデートしろとのことですが
CentOS上でupdateするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Node.jsのupdateの件

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Vagrantはあくまで(入れ物としての)仮想環境を用意するためのツールに過ぎないので、今回の質問の内容としてはCentOSを主眼に置くべきかと思います。

Comment: @cubick 私も最初そう思ったのですが、インターネットからファイルをどうダウンロードしてくるかに選択肢が出てくるなと思ったので Vagrant と CentOS を併記する形にした、という経緯でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

出力に書かれているウェブサイト https://nodejs.org/en/download/ から新しい NodeJS をインストールしましょう。

### NodeSource を使う方法

[ダウンロードページのここ](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages)に書かれているように、Node.js 公式のパッケージ・リポジトリとして [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) というのが管理されており、このリポジトリを yum に登録すると yum install できるようになります。

が、2020 年 4 月現在 CentOS 6 はサポート対象外です。このため、**思い切って新しいバージョンの CentOS を使うというのも選択肢です**。

※CentOS 6 も[助けようとしてくれてはいる](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/OLDER_DISTROS.md)のですが、最近の Node.js をインストールするには glibc のバージョンが古くて上手くいかないという issue が立っています: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/859 あるいは、今回必要とされている程度に Node.js のバージョンを下げれば対応できるかもしれません。

### 配布されている Node.js バイナリを使う方法

※最新バージョンを入れようとするとそれなりに大変です。古いバージョンを使うと（セキュリティ的な問題はおいておけば）ラクです。どのくらい古ければ良いかについては [cubick さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65928/19110)をご覧ください。

https://nodejs.org/en/download/ からバイナリをダウンロードします。

- 選択肢1: 公開されている Linux Binaries の URL を直接 wget または curl する。

  ```sh
  wget https://nodejs.org/dist/vほにゃらら/node-ほにゃらら-linux-ほにゃらら.tar.xz
  ```
- 選択肢2: ホスト OS で普通にダウンロードし、Vagrant の synced folder を経由してゲスト OS に移す。

圧縮されているので展開します。

```sh
tar Jxfv node-vほにゃらら-linux-ほにゃらら.tar.xz
```

あとはこのフォルダを適当な場所に mv し、bin フォルダに PATH を通せば node コマンドは認識されます。公式 wiki を参考にしてください: https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation

```sh
# 例（必要に応じて先頭に sudo をつけてください）
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs
mv node-vほにゃらら-linux-ほにゃらら /usr/local/lib/nodejs/
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-vほにゃらら-linux-ほにゃらら/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

これで `node --version` が新しくなっていれば無事終了です。

しかし CentOS 6 では `node --version` が以下のように glibc などが見つからないというエラーを出す場合があります。

```
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

実際調べるとこんな感じで古いものしか無いと分かります：

```sh
# strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

という訳で glibc を新しいものにしましょう。たとえば自分で gcc のソースコードからビルドして入れ替える方法があります。この回答で解説し始めると長くなりすぎるので、ブログ記事にリンクしておきます: [CentOS 6 の stdlibc++ を更新する](http://dotnsf.blog.jp/archives/1064353059.html)

Comment: 初心者ですいません。。おそらく頓珍漢なことを聞いてしまうかと思うのですが
”公開されている Linux バイナリの URL を直接 wget または curlする ”　とありますが
こちらのURLとは何のことでしょうか？
例えばwget https://nodejs.org/en/download/　としてもヴァージョンに変化はないようです。また、２番目の方法である”ホスト OS で普通にダウンロードし、Vagrant の synced folder を経由してゲスト OS に移す”　とありますがダウンロードしたファイルをMACの/home/mypc/内に移しexport PATH=/home/mypc//node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATHとコマンドしてみましたが全くヴァージョンは変化ありません。こちらは何か抜け落ちているということでしょうか？

Comment: 展開しましたか？

Comment: wget に関しては、選択肢 1 の中に書かれているコマンドを参考にしてください。Linux Binaries としてリンクされているものがこのような URL になっています。

Comment: PATH を通しても認識されない件について、synced folder は追加で設定しない限りはリアルタイムな更新とはならないので、Vagrant 側からそのファイルが見えているかも確認してみてください。`ls /home/mypc` して見えるかどうか、など。また、普通は `/home/mypc` というパスではなく `/usr/local` などに移動しておくのが便利です（ユーザー依存ではないパスになるため）。

Comment: ありがとうございます。展開はしました。まず、選択肢１についてですがターミナルにてコマンドでインストールする方法かと思いますが、下記のコマンドをしてみました。$ wget https://nodejs.org/dist/node-v12.16.2-linux-x64

すると

--2020-04-23 03:27:01--  https://nodejs.org/dist/node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
Resolving nodejs.org... 104.20.22.46, 104.20.23.46, 2606:4700:10::6814:162e, ...
Connecting to nodejs.org|104.20.22.46|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-04-23 03:27:02 ERROR 404: Not Found.

と出ました。エラーが出ているのでうまくいっていないかと思われます。。
バージョンをみてもv0.10.48と出て変わっておりません。

Comment: また、選択肢２についてですが、画像を上記に貼り付けました。
見ての通りVagrantのフォルダを開いてもsynced folder などというフォルダはないようです。。。これは特赦な作業をしないと出てこないのでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107067/discussion-between-nekketsuuu-and-ligtning)しましょう。

Answer (score 2):

#### 前置き

理想としては CentOS6 の環境で動く Node.js のバージョンを確認したいところですが、
リリースノート等を見ても参考になりそうな情報が見当たりません。

今回は `rails` 実行時のエラーに出ている "node.js の v8.16.0 以上が必要" と出ているので、

> `Webpacker requires Node.js >= 8.16.0 and you are using 0.10.48`

[Node.js のダウンロードページ](https://nodejs.org/ja/download/releases/) からリンクを辿って [v8.16.2](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.16.2/) を選択してみます。
linuxの64bit版を例に進めますが、実際の環境に合わせて読み替えてください。

また、余計なトラブルを避けるため、OS標準パッケージでインストールされた node.js は
事前にいったん削除しておくことをおすすめします。

```
$ sudo yum remove nodejs -y
```

---

#### ダウンロードとインストール手順

ファイルをダウンロード (ファイル名と拡張子に注意)

```
$ curl -O https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.16.2/node-v8.16.2-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

インストール先をここでは `/usr/local/lib/nodejs/` 以下とし、必要なディレクトリを作成してから
アーカイブを展開

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs
$ sudo tar xJvf node-v8.16.2-linux-x64.tar.xz -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

ディレクトリの配置を確認

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/nodejs/
node-v8.16.2-linux-x64/
```

設定ファイル (ここでは `~/.bashrc`) に追記して環境変数 PATH を通す

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.16.2-linux-x64/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

設定ファイルを読み直して PATH が通っているかと、node.js のバージョンを確認

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
$ which node
/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v8.16.2-linux-x64/bin/node
$ node -v
v8.16.2
```