# CentOS6 で SQLite を3.8 以上にアップグレードするには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, sqlite

Railsでサーバーを立ち上げ、ChromeブラウザでIPアドレスを入力し開いたところ、下記のような画面が表示されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これはSQLiteを3.8以上にするようにということでしょうが
アップデートの方法が調べてもわかりませんでした。
CentoOS6の環境でアップデートするにはどのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: Rails 6 をお使いのようですが、[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65861/19110)でおっしゃっていたようにドットインストールの[この講座](https://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_rails_v3)を受けてらっしゃるのだとすると Rails 5 にバージョンが固定されているはずです。Rails のバージョンは合っていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。この度は親切丁寧に教えてくださり大変助かります。他の方からアドヴァイスを受けて、一度CentOS7で環境構築してみようと思います。またわからないことがあれば別途ご質問させてください。この度は本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65861) でのやり取りと根本的な原因は同じで、CentOS6 の標準パッケージで提供されているSQLiteのバージョンとしては **v3.6.20** が最新です。参考までに CentOS7 でも **v3.7.17** までしか利用できません。

SQLite の v3.8 以降が必要な場合には、[公式サイトからソースコード](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) を入手し、コンパイルして自力でインストールする必要があります。現時点では v3.31.1 が最新版です。

**手順**

```
$ curl -O https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3310100
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

---

**蛇足な補足**

CentOS は "枯れた" (=安定した) バージョンのパッケージを採用するディストリビューションになるので、一部を除いて収録されているアプリやライブラリのメジャーバージョンが上がる事はほぼありません。

安定運用が求められる用途向けのLinuxなので、**最新版**のコードを使用するような開発向けにはあまり向きません。CentOS6を使い続ける限り、今後も同じような問題が出続ける可能性があるでしょう。

(ドキュメントがメンテされていなさそうなので、「ドットインストール」のサイト自体がお手本として参照するのにあまり向かないような気がします)

Comment: 現在やはりCentOS６でやるには無理があるそうですね。。
一度、CentOS7でやってみます。またわからないことがあれば別途ご質問させてください。この度は本当にありがとうございます。