# CentOS6 上で rails new できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, vagrant

vagrant で環境構築後、CentOS6 上で `rails new` を実行するとエラーが発生します。

```
rails new ディレクトリ名
```

以下エラーメッセージ

```
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vagrant/railslessons/mytest/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
         run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
Using i18n 1.8.5
Using minitest 5.14.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.7
Using zeitwerk 2.4.0
Using activesupport 6.0.3.2
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.9.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.10
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.7.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 6.0.3.2
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.0.3.2
Using nio4r 2.5.2
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
Using actioncable 6.0.3.2
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 6.0.3.2
Using activemodel 6.0.3.2
Using activerecord 6.0.3.2
Using mimemagic 0.3.5
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 6.0.3.2
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.0.3.2
Using actionmailer 6.0.3.2
Using actiontext 6.0.3.2
Using public_suffix 4.0.5
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.3.3
Using bootsnap 1.4.8
Using bundler 1.17.2
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 1.7.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.33.0
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using ffi 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.10.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.2.1
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using puma 4.3.5
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using thor 1.0.1
Using railties 6.0.3.2
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 6.0.3.2
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Fetching sassc 2.4.0
Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby -I
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20200827-7966-4bspp5.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/ast.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [ast.o] エラー 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/sassc-2.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sassc (2.4.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sass-rails was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
    sassc-rails was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
      sassc
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
       rails  webpacker:install
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

エラー内容の通り

```
gem install sassc -v '2.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

を実行すると

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sassc:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200827-8009-1scbkg5.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/ast.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [ast.o] エラー 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/sassc-2.4.0/gem_make.out
```

以上のエラーが発生します。

[railsでサーバーが立ち上がらず、sassc でエラーが出る: cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option “-std=c++11”](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65787)

この質問の回答を参考に、

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

が主原因(C++コンパイラの導入失敗かバージョンが古い)のではないかとのことで
XcodeのCommand Line Toolsをインストールをしてclang++ を更新しようとしましたが、
インストール しても `clang++ --version` が実行できず、

```
-bash: clang++: コマンドが見つかりません
```

とでてしまいます。

## 補足

- CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
- Rails 6.0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Rails を動かそうとしている CentOS に入っている gcc のバージョンが古いために native extension のビルドに失敗しているようです。
なのでホストOSである macOS 側に何かを入れる必要はありません。

参考にされたという質問の方でも丁寧に回答されている方がいらっしゃいますが、CentOS 6 に標準で入る gcc のバージョンが古いために発生しているので、以下の記事などを参考に CentOS 上の gcc のバージョンを上げてから再度試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

https://qiita.com/rafilia/items/304a45bb0b5fa137bff1

https://tech.withsin.net/2018/06/05/centos6-gcc48/

Answer (score 0):

(この回答はマルチポストです。)
https://teratail.com/questions/287980#reply-408429

CentOS 6標準のGCCは4.4.7と古く、C++11に未対応のため、`--std=c++11`オプションが動作しません。sasscパッケージのコンパイルにはC++11対応が必須のため、インストールできないという状況です。

解決方法は3つ

1. CentOS 7またはCentOS 8を使用する。(推奨)

CentOS 6はまもなくサポートが終了します。レガシーな環境のテストなどといった目的以外で、使用することは推奨できません。新しく開発に使用する環境としては、全く適していません。

CentOS 7またはCentOS 8を使用してください。こちらのGCCはバージョンが新しいため、C++11に対応しています。CentOS 8の方が最新ですが、古い資料のやり方ではうまくいかない場合があるので、ある程度チャレンジ精神が求められます。

2. CentOS 6に最新のGCCを入れる。

CentOS 6上のパッケージを最新にしても、GCCのバージョンは上がらず、パッチのみが適用されます。そのため、通常のパッケージでC++11対応にすることは不可能です。

最もオーソドックスなやり方は[GCCのサイト](https://gcc.gnu.org/)からGCCをダウンロードして自分でコンパイルして導入することです。ただ、それなりの知識は必要ですので、Linuxに慣れていない場合はお勧めできません。

3. sasscではなくレガシーなsassを使う。

かつてSassはピュアRubyで書かれており、コンパイル不要でした。そのパッケージがsassです。こちらを使えばコンパイルの問題は解決します。

ただし、ピュアRubyなsassは既に開発が終了しており、コンパイル前提のsasscを使用するように開発者は促しています。レガシーなsassにバグ等があっても修正はされず、また、新機能も追加されませんので、どうしてもと言う必要性がない限り、使用しない方が良いです。

sasscではなくsassを強制的に使う方法はGemfileについての知識を持った上で、依存関係を無理矢理変更する作業がいるため、ある程度の知識が必要になります。

Answer (score 0):

[CentOS7のとき](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/66035/2808)と同じノリで

> 公式のGetting Started, [4.1 Starting up the Web Server](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#starting-up-the-web-server)で `rails server`コマンドを実行し、 "Yay! You’re on Rails!"のページが表示されるところまで確認しました:

```sh
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum -y install gdbm-devel openssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel


# GCC4
pushd /tmp
curl -s -L -O http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/gcc/releases/gcc-4.9.4/gcc-4.9.4.tar.gz
tar xf gcc-4.9.4.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.9.4
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/opt/gcc-4.9.4 --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib
make -j 5
sudo make install
# https://qiita.com/knutpb1205/items/4a9b39bf69f1788ef69c#%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96
sudo mv /opt/gcc-4.9.4/lib64/{,bak.}libstdc++.so.6.0.20-gdb.py
sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gcc-4.9.4.conf' << EOF
/opt/gcc-4.9.4/lib64
EOF
sudo ldconfig
echo 'export PATH=/opt/gcc-4.9.4/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
popd

# SQLite >= 3.8 インストール(ここでは3.31.1をインストール)
# https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
curl -s https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp
cd /tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3310100
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

# node インストール
# 新しいバージョンは要求するglibcのバージョンが大きいので利用できない
# https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-node-js-and-yarn
# https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/
mkdir -p ~/opt
curl -sL https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.17.0/node-v8.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz | tar xJ -C ~/opt
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/opt/node-v8.17.0-linux-x64/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# yarn インストール
npm install -g yarn

# rbenv, rbenv-build インストール
# https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
mkdir -p "$(rbenv root)"/plugins
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build

# ruby インストール
rbenv install 2.6.5
rbenv global 2.6.5

# sqlite3 利用設定
# https://url4u.jp/centos7-rails6-sqlite3/
bundle config build.sqlite3 "--with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/local/lib"

# rails インストール
# https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails
gem install rails
```

[サンプルVagrantfile](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso69924)